# Send binary String in Windows Sidebar Gadget via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sidebar

Im trying to send a File to my server from a Windows Sidebar Gadget. I found this Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/23fad87b-8aad-4262-8c2c-b1fe0ca3b9f6/file-upload-with-sidebar-gadget?forum=sidebargadfetdevelopment

```
var adTypeBinary = 1;
var cfItem = System.Shell.chooseFile(true, "", "", "");

if (cfItem.path != "") {

   oStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
   oStream.Type = adTypeBinary;
   oStream.Open;

   oStream.LoadFromFile(cfItem.path);
   content = oStream.Read;

   //upload content (as binary string)

   oStream.Close;
   oStream = null;
}
```

But this only explains how to read a file, not how to upload the resulting binary string. I tried several techniques (Blob, Uint8Array, ..) but none of them is working. Windows Sidebar has Internet Explorer 7 Standards.

If somebody provided a solution, this would be great (Either with jquery or plain javascript)

Comment: Does really nobody have a solution for me?...